# MySQL JOIN one to many separated by hyphens

Tags: mysql, join

I was wondering if it is possible to do this with MySQL:

I have two tables:

thresholds (table)

-idThreshold (field)
-Name (field)

threshold_results (table)

-idThreshold (field)
-idResult (field)

One threshold can have many results

I would like a SELECT that shows the results for each threshold in this way

Example:

```
Threshold(column)   idResults(column)
idThreshold1        IdResult1-IdResult2-idResult3
idThreshold2        IdResult1
idThreshold3        IdResult2-idResult3
idThreshold4
idThreshold5        IdResult7
```

Thank you!

Comment: do you really want to concatenate the results? or do you want another aggregate function on this?

Comment: I would like to concatenate them using a hyphen. I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
select t.name, group_concat(distinct r.idResult separator '-') as results
from threshold t
left join threshold_results r on r.idThreshold = t.idThreshold 
group by t.idThreshold, t.name
```

Comment: Thank you!. that seems is getting closer to what I want, but I get the results repeated many times. 'THRESHOLD1', '1221-1221-1221-1221-1221-1221'. Any idea?

Comment: Use the `distinct` keyword:  `group_concat(distinct r.idResult separator '-')`.